# How to reboot a dynamically calculated host in ansible

Tags: ansible

How to reboot a host using ansible, **this host is not the remote host stored in the inventory file**. The host IP is getting returned from a script called `get_active_host.sh`. I tried to reboot the active host from the script itself however , playbook execution failed even after using `wait_for_connection` . the host which should be rebooted is stored in `{{ active_host_location }}`

```
---
# tasks file for GET_ACTIVE_HOST
 - name: GET ACTIVE HOST LOCATION
   script: get_active_host.sh
   args:
     executable: bash
   register: active_host_location
   async: 0
   poll: 0
   become: true

 - name: Wait for server to restart
   local_action:
     module: wait_for
       host={{ active_host_location }}
       port=22
       delay=1
       timeout=300



[my current machine] --->[ansible_host]---get_active_host.sh-->[active_host]
   1.2.3.4                   1.2.3.5                             1.2.3.6
```

I need to reboot `1.2.3.6` which is dynamically calculated during the play from the script.                  Is it possible to achieve it and how ?

script output:

```
./get_active_host.sh
1.2.3.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable you need is being outputted from the script already, you should be pretty close. When you register the output of a task, it dumps a whole bunch of stuff into a `results` object that you then need to dig into to grab the actual variable you need. Use the debug module on `active_host_location` to figure out the exact hierarchy, but what you want is probably something like, `{{ active_host_location.results.stdout }}`.

Answer (score 1):

The IP returned from the script is saved in the structure of `active_host_location` variable, and since the output is a single line you can access the IP by `active_host_location.stdout`.

Since the script returns IP and not hostname, i think you cant populate in advance all these possible results in your inventory, for ansible to be able to connect with provisioned user/pass and run the reboot tasks. So, i would try to do the `restart` task with a locally run ssh command, that connects via ssh to the target machine, and runs the reboot.

To connect to the machine, you can:

1. exchange SSH heys
2. install `sshpass` in your localhost.

if you follow 1, the shell task would look like:

```
  - name: Run restart command
    shell: "ssh {{ remote_user }}{{ active_host_location.stdout }} 'sudo reboot'"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: reboot_result

  - name: print result
    debug:
      var: reboot_result
```

if you want to use `sshpass` approach, the command task could be:

```
  - name: Run restart command
    shell: "sshpass -p \"{{ remote_pass }}\" ssh {{ remote_user }}@{{ active_host_location.stdout }} 'sudo reboot'"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: reboot_result

  - name: print result
    debug:
      var: reboot_result
```

these assume this user can "sudo without requiring to submit password".

hope these help

Comment: thank you for your kind help, I learnt that `active_host_location.stdout` and `active_host_location.stdout[0]` are different today!